# Notable work in social or personality psychology regarding social networking?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, personality, behaviorism

Today most of the people spend a lot of time socializing. What people post on Facebook/Twitter or any other social platform directly or indirectly reflects a person's psyche. I've developed a habit of studying patterns/behaviours of people while on social networks. I would very much like to study it methodically.

Is there a notable work done in this regard? I'm looking for a book or blog or anything that explores the topic in depth.